# Include a dll fil in an exe file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013

I have an  dll file which I have to include in my project. I want to include the file in the exe file, so they just have to download one file!
I didn't find any answer that worked for me!

Comment: Zip will certainly do that - maybe you should explain more.

Comment: I basicly have ONE single Exe file which requires a dll-File.
I want ONE exe file!

Comment: Do you have source code for both the exe and the dll?

Comment: No, I have the sourcecode which requires a dll file  (from another person/company)

Comment: Ok then if the dll is .NET too, maybe you should look at the answer from @zey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) tool !
This tool can be used to merge multiple .NET assemblies into a single assembly.